# Parsing Multidimensional JSON

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2009-07-06",
        "Open": "406.50",
        "High": "410.64",
        "Low": "401.66",
        "Close": "409.61",
        "Volume": "2262600",
        "Adj Close": "409.61"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2009-07-02",
        "Open": "415.41",
        "High": "415.41",
        "Low": "406.81",
        "Close": "408.49",
        "Volume": "2517600",
        "Adj Close": "408.49"
    }
]
```

I'm confident that it's valid JSON, but I'm not sure how to parse it with jQuery's $.parseJSON().  I'm running into a problem because the two major groups don't have titles, I think.  It creates a list of objects, but I don't know how to access those objects.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates an array of objects, like so:

```
var json = '[{"Date": "2009-07-06","Open": "406.50","High": "410.64","Low": "401.66","Close": "409.61","Volume": "2262600","Adj Close": "409.61"},{"Date": "2009-07-02","Open": "415.41","High": "415.41","Low": "406.81","Close": "408.49","Volume": "2517600","Adj Close": "408.49"}]';

var valid = $.parseJSON(json);
```

accessed like

```
valid[0]; // first one
valid[1]; // second one
valid[1].Open; //Open in second one
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uzHXh/1/)